# C++ using function template in class template

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <int C> class MyClass;

...     


template <int C>
double trans(MyClass<C> &a)
{
    //return some double 
}

//this is supposed to be function template
template <int C>
double func(MyClass<2> &a)
{
    //return some double
}

template <int C>
MyClass<C-1> func(MyClass<C> &a)
{
    MyClass<C-1> ret;
    return ret;
}

template <int C>
double otherFunc(MyClass<C> &a)
{
     double result;
     if(C == SOME_CONSTANT)
         result = func(a);
     else
         result = trans(func(a));

}
```

What my problem is I want to check template argument C in parameter `otherFunc` call function template `func` (return double) instead of member function of class template `func`(return MyClass). But somehow compiler attempts to `func` that returns MyClass in

```
     if(C == SOME_CONSTANT)
         result = func(a);
```

this part so I got compiler error (because double = MyClass is not viable). How should I fix this problem?

Comment: `otherFunc` needs to be legal to compile for the values of `C` it's instantiated with - that *includes* the branch in the `if`/`else` statement that can never be taken for that value of `C`.  In other words, even if `SOME_CONSTANT` is `2`, it will still check the legality of the `result = func(a)` code when `C` is not `2` - leading to the conversion error you're seeing.  How to fix? - you could avoid the `if`/`else` by havnig a general `otherFunc` template for `C != 2` and a specialisation for `2`.  It's not very clear what you're really trying to achieve though....

Comment: I just want to make `func` behaves slightly different than other when C == 2. I'd appreciate it if you can elaborate bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to elaborate in a comment, so I'll post an answer.  To recap what I said in comments:

- you can't have an `if`/`else` in `otherFunc` that won't be legal to compile for a specific `MyClass` instantiation,
- you ***can*** use the same template specialisation approach to create an alternative `otherFunc` definition to handle `MyClass<2>`s.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int C>
class MyClass
{ };

template <int C>
double trans(const MyClass<C> &a)
{
    return C + 700;
}

template <int C>
MyClass<C-1> func(MyClass<C> &a)
{
    MyClass<C-1> ret;
    return ret;
}


double func(MyClass<2>& a)
{
    return 200.0;
}

template <int C>
double otherFunc(MyClass<C> &a)
{
     return trans(func<C>(a));
}

template <>
double otherFunc<2>(MyClass<2>& a)
{
    return func(a);
}


int main()
{
    MyClass<2> a;
    std::cout << otherFunc(a) << '\n';

    MyClass<4> b;
    std::cout << otherFunc(b) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
200
703
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still kinda trying to learn template in c++ :/ I couldn't quite get the idea of specialization

Comment: @REALFREE: the syntax takes some getting used to ;-).

Comment: Oh btw I have one more question, so you remove template from double func(MyClass<2>& a), is this still a class template function?

Comment: @REALFREE: no - I've "*overloaded*" the template with another non-template function dedicated to `MyClass<2>`s arguments.  This is necessary to have a different return type.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is that:

```
 if(C == SOME_CONSTANT)
     result = func(a);
 else
     result = trans(func(a));
```

is checked in the runtime, while template specializations and type check is done during compilation. Those 2 functions:

```
 template <int C>
 double func(MyClass<2> &a)
 {
     //return some double
 }

 template <int C>
 MyClass<C-1> func(MyClass<C> &a)
 {
     MyClass<C-1> ret;
     return ret;
 }
```

have almost the same signatures - the only difference is that for `C==2` is used the one returning `double`, otherwise used the one returning `MyClass<2>`. So what you get is:

```
 // for C==2
 if(C == SOME_CONSTANT)
     result = func<2>(a); // returns double - just like you wanted
 else
     result = trans<2>(func<2>(a)); // pass double into trans<?>(MyClass<?>), so the parameter cannot be resolved unless you specified some implicit constructor/explicit conversion operator 

 // for e.g. C==3
 if(C == SOME_CONSTANT)
     result = func<3>(a); // returns MyClass<2> while result is double
 else
     result = trans<2>(func<3>(a)); // pass MyClass<2> into trans<?>(MyClass<>) - like you wanted
```

so basically your code have invalid type for specializations in either first or second case. You can do something like this instead:

```
 template <>
 MyClass<2> func<2>(MyClass<2> &a)
 {
     return a;
 }

 template <int C>
 MyClass<C-1> func(MyClass<C> &a)
 {
     return MyClass<C-1>;
 }
```

to keep templates type consistent, and then:

```
if(C == SOME_CONSTANT)
   result = trans(a);
else
   result = trans(func(a));
```

It's just an example how to handle it. Things should be easier if you avoid messing with different return typed for different template specializations.